# Objects literal and 'this' in submodule pattern

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

Im working in a sub-module pattern code. Want to create sub-modules with objects literals, the problem is `this` for the objects inside the sub-module is MODULE and not my object literal. Any idea?

```
var MODULE.sub = (function () {

   var myObject = {

       key: value,

       method: function () {
           this.key // this = MODULE and not MyObject... :(
       }

   };

   return myObject.method;

}(MODULE));
```

Comment: How are you creating and calling your sub module? Better, provide a fiddle.

Comment: If you called it like `Module.sub.method()`, then `Module.sub`, `myObject` and the `this` inside `method` should be the same object.

Comment: The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jZVwv/2/

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: Notice that he does not export `myObject`, but the only the function

Comment: @Bergi it was edited 15 hours ago. Originally, `myObject` was exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... just return a function in MODULE.sub calling the public method.  I don't know if is the best approach

```
var MODULE.sub = (function () {

   var myObject = {

       key: value,

       method: function () {
           this.key // this = myObject :)
       }

   };

   return function () {
        myObject.method();
    }

}(MODULE));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var MODULE = MODULE || {};   
MODULE.sub = (function () {

   return {

       myObject : {

           key : 10,

           method : function() {
              console.log(this.key);
           }

       }
   };

})();
```

Then call it:

```
MODULE.sub.myObject.method();
```

You were only returning the method and not the key so "this" would be undefined. You could keep it private if you want like this and pass key in as a var:

```
  var MODULE = MODULE || {};
  MODULE.sub = (function () {

      var key = 10,

   return {

       myObject : {



           method : function() {
              console.log(key);
           }

       }
   };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)s value depends on how the function is called. So if you assign that function to `MODULE.sub`, and then invoke it as `MODULE.sub(…)`, then `this` will point to the `MODULE` of course. If you had invoked it as `myObject.method(…)`, then `this` would point to that object.

So you either should expose the whole `myObject` (like in @BingeBoys answer), or do not export that function and expect it to be a method of `myObject`. Instead, you could use a [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) one:

```
return myObject.method.bind(myObject);
```

or the explicit equivalent of that

```
return function() {
    return myObject.method();
};
```

or you would not put the function as `method` on that object at all:

```
…
    var myObject = {
        key: value,
    };
    return function() {
        myObject.key // no `this` here
        …
    };
…
```